# How do I show a Spinner while my React app is loading?

Tags: office-js, office-ui-fabric

Is it possible to show a [Spinner](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/spinner/spinner) while my Word add-in (react app) is loading?

Obviously to use a Spinner you need to compile a React app, so I guess another way of stating the question is: is there a standalone version of the fabric Spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since React is not loaded yet, I would personally within the `<div id="root">` Add the recommended CSS/HTML. Once React components gets loaded (Downloaded), it will automatically replace the "root" contents.

For example:

```
<body>
  <noscript>
     You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root">
    <style>
        #loader {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            display: flex;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .spinner {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 5em;
            height: 5em;
            margin: 60px auto;
            font-size: 10px;
            position: relative;
            border-top: 0.5em solid rgb(199, 224, 244);
            border-right: 0.5em solid rgb(199, 224, 244);
            border-bottom: 0.5em solid rgb(199, 224, 244);
            border-left: 0.5em solid rgb(0, 120, 212);
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
            -webkit-animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
            animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes load8 {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes load8 {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <div id="loader">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Your index.tsx would just be:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I ended up with. My "home-rolled" spinner ended up looking like this: https://jsfiddle.net/t5wahc9v/

Comment: Awesome @Fergie looks really nice! Bookmarking it myself!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is fabric core.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/get-started#core

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core

If it's not there, then there is no standalone spinner and you need to open an issue according to them.

Comment: As far as I can see, Fabric Core just has styles not components- or maybe I am looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Mike from the Fabric team here. Fabric Core is primarily focused on the styles that make up the design language. However, it does have some basic components (like a grid) and a simple spinner could be a great addition if you'd like to open an issue. To get you unblocked for now, here's a quick prototype using an icon from Fabric Core: https://codesandbox.io/s/q3npzrj6o9

Comment: Thanks Mike- yes, I ended up reverse engineering the spinner, and adding it inline to the host page. Here is the code for anybody who is looking for some copypasta: https://jsfiddle.net/t5wahc9v/